# Ruby recursive shuffle with rand

Tags: ruby

I am quite new to Ruby and programming in general, and I am currently trying to study with Chris Pine's book. In chapter 10 there is a task that requires you to return a shuffled version of an array.

I tried the following code for the shuffle method itself, and it worked:

```
def shuffle array
  recursive_shuffle array, []   
end

def recursive_shuffle unshuffled, shuffled
  if unshuffled.length == 1
    shuffled.push unshuffled[0]
    shuffled.pop                      
    return shuffled
  end

  rand_index = rand(unshuffled.length - 1)
  shuffled.push unshuffled[rand_index]
  unshuffled.delete_at(rand_index)
  recursive_shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled)
end

puts(shuffle(array))
```

I'm wondering about two things.

First I tried doing it without `shuffled.pop` and with `rand_index = rand(unshuffled.length)` instead of `length - 1`.

However, in the answer the element before the last one was always blank, otherwise it was shuffled and no elements were missing. Then I thought the problem should be in the `rand` and added the `- 1`.

At this point the array was, again, shuffled properly, but this time there was always one blank last element of the shuffled array. That's why I added `shuffled.pop`.

It works fine like this, but I don't understand why it adds a blank element in the first two instances.

Also, if I have an array of 2 elements, its length should be 2 and `rand_index` should be `rand(1)`, but isn't `rand(1)` supposed to always be 0? The aforementioned code nevertheless shuffles properly arrays with 2 elements.

I looked at various other topics on Ruby, shuffle, and rand, and couldn't find a similar problem.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work "fine like this."  The last element is omitted by your shuffle.

Comment: The statement of your task does not include the word "recursive", which you've used in the title. The use of recursion is just one option. In fact, I think most Rubiests would not use recursion for this problem. If you are interested in a range of suggestions for dealing with the problem I suggest you limit the reference to "recusion" to the method you used.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Cary Swoveland, you're right, it does not, but I wanted to see if I can do it with recursion, as it is still a new concept for me. However, I don't mind seeing other suggestions, too. :)

Answer (score 2):

The first block in your shuffle method:

```
if unshuffled.length == 1
  shuffled.push unshuffled[0]
  shuffled.pop                      
  return shuffled
end
```

Doesn't do what you want it to be doing.

If `unshuffled.length` is `1`, then there is only one element in the array, so you can just add it to your shuffled array and return the shuffled array with something like:

```
if unshuffled.length == 1
  return shuffled.push(unshuffled.pop)
end
```

or, sticking with your original approach:

```
if unshuffled.length == 1
  shuffled.push unshuffled[0]                   
  return shuffled
end
```

Also, calling `push` pushes a new element onto the end of the array that you're calling `push` on. E.g. if `a = [1, 2]`, then `a.push(3)` yields `[1, 2, 3]`.

Calling `pop` on an array, "pops" the last element off of the array. E.g. if `a = [1, 2, 3]` and you call `a.pop`, then `a == [1, 2]`.

Putting these two concepts together, you can see that if you push something onto an array and then pop it right back off, you're not accomplishing much. E.g. if you call `a = [1, 2]` and then `a.push(3)`, then `a` looks like `[1, 2, 3]`. Calling `a.pop` puts you back at `[1, 2]`.

The other issue is the call to `rand` (as @pjs mentioned in the comments). 
`rand` will return a random integer less than the (non-zero) integer you supply, so there's no need to decrement the `length` you're passing to it. The `rand` line can be changed to:  `rand_index = rand(unshuffled.length - 1)`

Integrating this change should leave you with something similar to this:

```
def recursive_shuffle unshuffled, shuffled
  if unshuffled.length == 1
    return shuffled.push(unshuffled.pop)
  end

  rand_index = rand(unshuffled.length)
  shuffled.push unshuffled[rand_index]
  unshuffled.delete_at(rand_index)
  recursive_shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled)
end
```

Which should work fine.

This could be shortened further to something like:

```
def recursive_shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled = [])
  return shuffled.push(unshuffled.pop) if unshuffled.length == 1
  shuffled.push(unshuffled.delete_at(rand(unshuffled.length)))
  recursive_shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled)
end
```

Or even:

```
def recursive_shuffle(arr)
  return arr if arr.length == 1
  shuffle = [arr.sample]
  shuffle + recursive_shuffle(arr - shuffle)
end
```

Comment: Still doesn't work properly, if you print the returned shuffled array you'll find the last element *never* gets moved.  Use `rand(unshuffled.length)` rather than `rand(unshuffled.length - 1)`.  Other improvements can be added:  1) make the `if` an `if/else` and you can lose the explicit `return`;  2) the front end function can be eliminated by making the recursive function `def shuffle(unshuffled, shuffled = [])`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @pjs. Incorporated most of your suggestions above.

Comment: you wrote `return shuffled.push(unshuffled.pop)`, what is unshuffled.pop, is it an empy array or an operation?

Comment: `unshuffled` is an array and I'm calling `pop` on it. In this particular case, `unshuffled` is an array containing one element. Calling `unshuffled.pop` is removing the last element from `unshuffled` (emptying it in this case), and returning that value. This means that `shuffled.push(unshuffled.pop)` pushes (appends) the return value of `unshuffled.pop` to the `shuffled` array. tldr: `unshuffled.pop` is the element that was in the last position of the `unshuffled` array.

Comment: @dinjas thank you `unshuffled.pop is the element that was in the last position of the unshuffled array` for instance if unshuffled = ["a"], unshuffled.pop is the string "a", right?

Comment: @kouty correct. if `unshuffled == ["a"]`, and you do `x = unshuffled.pop`, then you'll find that `x == "a"`, and `unshuffled == []`

Comment: and if `unshuffled == ["a", 3]`, and you do `x = unshuffled.pop`, then you'll find that `x == 3` and `unshuffled == ["a"]`

Comment: dinjas, pjs, thank you for your suggestions. I think I am fairly familiar with the concepts of push and pop, and to some extent rand. That is why I was perplexed.
Despite everything mentioned, for me the program seems to work just fine even with 1 element in the array, with the push and pop, and with rand(unshuffled.length - 1). Initially I did it without the pop after the push, and with rand(unshuffled.length), as pjs mentioned. 
It is just that there always was a blank element in the answer - that is why I added them, even if they seem meaningless. I will think about it more.

Comment: I forgot to mention the beginning of my code, which fills the array:
   `array = []
    while true

 word = gets.chomp

 array.push word

 if word == ''
  break
 end

end`

Excuse me about that.

Comment: dinjas, I tried the long and short version of the recursive method you suggested, but, at least on my computer, it still includes blank elements, at different places on every run of the program.

Comment: @NikolayD I'm not sure what you're passing to it for an argument . I added another example.

Comment: I was passing the array that I got from this code at the beginning of the program:
`array = [] while true word = gets.chomp array.push word if word == '' break end end`
Thank you for the new example, too. :) I tried it after removing the blank second argument from the wrapper method above. It works, but it still has one blank element at a random place.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more Ruby-like way you could implement your own versions of `shuffle`. The steps are as follows:

- create the instance method `my_shuffle` on the class `Array`, to mimic the function of the instance method [Array#shuffle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) (but not bother with implementing the alternative way `shuffle` can be used: `shuffle(random: rng) → new_ary`--see the doc).
- operate on a duplicate of `self` (the array to be shuffled) so that `self` is not "mutated" (altered).
- iterate on the enumerator `enum = arr.size.times`, which generates the sequence of numbers `0,1,...,arr.size-1`. The values of the sequence are not used in the block; all that is important is that the block is executed `arr.size` times.
- build an array represented by the block variable `a` by randomly deleting an element of `arr` and pushing it onto `a`.

**Code**

```
class Array
  def my_shuffle
    arr = self.dup
    arr.size.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| a << arr.delete_at(rand(arr.size)) }
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
[1,3,2,7,4,1].my_shuffle
  #=> [2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 7]
```

**Explanation**

Firstly, I've used [Enumerator#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) merely to save two steps (`a = []` and `a` below). It produces the same results as the following:

```
  def my_shuffle
    arr = self.dup
    a = []
    arr.size.times { a << arr.delete_at(rand(arr.size)) }
    a
  end
```

The array to be shuffled is:

```
ar = [1,3,2,7,4,1]
```

then

```
arr = ar.dup
  #=> [1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 1] 
n = arr.size
  #=> 6 
enum0 = n.times
  #=> #<Enumerator: 6:times> 
enum1 = enum0.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: 6:times>:with_object([])>
```

Carefully examine the return value of `enum1`. It may be thought of as a "compound enumerator". We can see the elements that will generated by `enum1` by converting it to an array:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[0, []], [1, []], [2, []], [3, []], [4, []], [5, []]]
```

The second element of each array corresponds to the block variable `a`. Initially it is an empty array because Enumerable#each_with_object's argument is `[]`.

We can send [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to `enum1` to generate the first element of the enumerator and set the block variables equal to that value:

```
b,a = enum1.next
  #=> [0, []]
```

The values of `b` and `a` are obtained by the use of *parallel assignment* (aka *multiple assignment*):

```
b #=> 0 
a #=> []
```

We can then perform the block calculation:

```
c = arr.delete_at(rand(ar.size))
  #=> arr.delete_at(rand(6))
  #=> arr.delete_at(4) 
  #=> 4 
a << c
  #=> [4]
```

`a` is now `[4]`, `arr` equals `[1, 3, 2, 7, 1]` and `ar` is unchanged.

As is customary, I have replaced the block variable `b` with an underscore because it is not used in the block calculation.

Next we have

```
b,a = enum1.next
  #=> [1, [4]] 
c = arr.delete_at(rand(ar.size))
  #=> arr.delete_at(rand(5))
  #=> arr.delete_at(0) 
  #=> 1 
a << c
  #=> [4, 1] 
arr
  #=> [3, 2, 7, 1]
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Comment: Thank you for the comment again! It seems a bit more complex for me at the moment, so I will revisit it soon. It is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal to get the array shuffled you should use the builtin `shuffle` method, it's both correct and faster than anything you'll write.

If your goal is to implement your own version, this is not well-suited to recursion and you should implement a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to avoid [bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias):

```
def fy_shuffle(arr)
  a_copy = arr.dup  # don't mutate original array!
  a_copy.each_index do |i|
    j = i + rand(a_copy.length - i)
    a_copy[i], a_copy[j] = a_copy[j], a_copy[i] if i != j
  end
end
```

If your goal is to learn about recursion, dinjas' answer fixes the problems in your original implementation and works as long as the arrays aren't large enough to blow out the stack.

Comment: I'm always amazed when a simple, obvious algorithm, such as this one, is named after the first person to write it down. *Fisher-Yates* offered an even simpler method, equivalent to simply drawing numbers out of a hat. I understand it's also called the *Knuth Shuffle*.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Don't be overly amazed, shuffling is one of those things that seems obvious but can be prone to subtle bugs.  See https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/ for a lovely exposition.

Comment: Thank you once more, pjs. The task was to develop your own version of a shuffle method. The same had to be done for a sorting method, too, before the shuffle. I will read about the Fisher-Yates shuffle.